# My Datanova Data Unifier model-maps throw "Rule parsing error. Span expected '(' at )"

Tags: integration, data-integration, fusion, unification

I'm using Datanova Fusion Hub and Data Unifier, version 3.4.0. I am mapping  a CSV data source to my central target model. It is a simple one-to-one mapping with a data transformation (adding a prefix to a string).

I get the error

```
java.lang.Exception: Rule parsing error. Span expected '(' at )
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your data transformation formulae and encoding.

All maps should be encoded in UTF-8.

All string parameters need to be in quotes. For example like "myParam" (ASCII 34).
Some editors put in different characters like “Fused” (ASCII 8220 and 8221).